# Filter imaginary numbers

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

In this task, you will be filtering out complex elements from an array.

> Create a `(4,)` array with values 3, 4.5, 3 + 5j and 0 using
>   "np.array()". Save it to a variable array
>
> Create a boolean condition real to retain only a real number using
>   `.isreal(array)`. (Note: `.isreal(array)` returns a Boolean value
>   which is `True` if the number inside the array is a real number and
>   False otherwise)
>
> Now apply this Boolean condition i.e. real on array using Boolean
>   indexing (explained in the topic) by `array[real]` and store it in
>   variable `real_array`.
>
> Similarly, create a Boolean condition `imag` to retain only complex
>   numbers which you can do it using `.iscomplex(array)`. This time create
>   an array `imag_array` which contains only complex numbers using the
>   Boolean condition `array[imag]` Test Cases: `imag_array[0] == (3+5j)`
>   `real_array[0] == (3 +0j)` and `real_array[1]== (4.5+0j)`

My Code:

```
# Code starts here
import numpy as np

# initialize array
array = np.array([3, 4.5, 3 + 5j, 0])

# boolean filter
real = array.isreal(array)
real_array = array[True, True, False, True]

# boolean filter
imag = array.iscomplex[array]
imag_array = array[False, False, True, False]

# Code ends here
```

What is the error ??

Comment: There's nothing wrong. There's no error. You just completed the 2nd part of the task.

Comment: The error is that `.iscomplex(array)` is not the same as `.iscomplex[array]`

Comment: First: you should also consider using `np.isreal(array)`, second: You cannot index the way you did. That indexing implies dimensions, you should rather do `array[real]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `iscomplex` function properly. You should change `imag = array.iscomplex[array]` to `imag = array.iscomplex(array)`, also it was showing me error for `array.isreal`, I changed it to `np.isreal(array)` and it worked.

```py
# Code starts here
import numpy as np

# initialize array
array = np.array([3, 4.5, 3 + 5j, 0])

# boolean filter
real = np.isreal(array)
real_array = array[real]

# boolean filter
imag = np.iscomplex(array)
imag_array = array[imag]
# Code ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reject_complex(arr):
    res = []
    for ii, bb in enumerate(np.iscomplex(arr)):
        if not bb:
            res.append(arr[ii])
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you came here looking for how to filter out imaginary numbers and get a list of the real values, this does that to `array`.

```
array[np.isreal(array)].real
```